# Error:(33, 13) Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+

Tags: android, facebook

Below is code from my build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        incremental false
    }
    dexOptions {
        dexInProcess false
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile files('libs/StartAppInApp-3.4.2.jar')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'
}
```

When I do Sync project with gradle files, it gives me error.

```
 Error:(33, 13) Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error?

Comment: global build.gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Answer (score 7):

The latest version 4.14.0 is not available at the moment.

Use 4.13.0 for the time being to avoid the gradle error.

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.13.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

use the specific version of facebook sdk like:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.14.0'
}
```

Comment: I trying but error Error:(40, 13) Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.14.0

Comment: try this:  compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.13.0'

Answer (score 0):

gradle will not allow any special symbles or charecters to resolve the repository.so use the facebooksdk for the specific version based on your requirement like bellow in dependency

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.8.2'
```

Comment: I want use newest version

Comment: i already described it's a sample dependency..read the description

Answer (score 0):

Version 4.14.1 has been deployed with the fix. So you can now go ahead and use the latest version via gradle. Specifying 4.+ will automatically use the 4.14.1 version.